# Azure Linux Zip Deploy not working : Azure Functions App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, azure-linux

I am trying to deploy Funtions app on Linux server on Azure.

I tried POC two days ago and I deployed it on Linux server and It was working fine. Zip file size was around 3.5 MB.

Then I added more code and packages and now the Zip file is sized at around 15 MB.

I am trying VS 2019 "Publish" to deploy this code to Azure but I am not getting any luck there. The same settings were working fine when I first created POC and deployed my code couple of times.

Here is the error I am getting,

[image: Error message from VS]

The file with logs also contains almost the same thing, they were unable to determine the cause of the error.

1. Does anyone else is facing this issue during covid19?
2. The code was working fine on the local machine but on Windows. Is it possible that there are Linux related errors in code?
3. Also, the DeployUI is getting a timeout just loading. https://xxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net:8181/ZipDeployUI/ What could be the possible fix for this?!

Thanks,
Kiran.

Comment: Are you sure the version on azure and on local is the same?

Comment: yes both are same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.I encountered the same issue when I deploy the linux function via vs2019, my issue is that I didn't set the Azure storage connection string.

```
[FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
```

2.This error message is not useful to identify the issue. You can go to Azure portal to see if there is any error message there.

3.The ZipDeployUI endpoint is `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI`, it doesn't work for Linux App Service at this time.

[image]

Reference:

[Troubleshoot error: "Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account)

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. Thanks for your answer, but I didn't work. I found the workaround. Posted it on this question. Also, We have setup Github actions for automated deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I did research and posting my own answer here,

1. Apparently there seems to be some timeout when I use VS2019 "Publish" Zip Deploy. It fails somewhere around 1 minute 40 seconds. So I used Azure CLI.
2. The code works fine on both Linux and Windows servers. It is more of a timeout issue because my zip size is a bit larger.
3. As said by @Tony Ju, it is possible that `ZipDeployUI` is not available for Linux server.

**Alternative to VS2019 Publish,**

Download Azure Cli from here, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest

Command to run for zip deploy,

`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src clouddrive/<filename>.zip`

Full documentation is here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip